# Doing a http authentication call with php

Tags: php, http

I already tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
file_get_contents('http://username:password@example.com/requested.file');
```

And

```
$auth = base64_encode("username:password");
$context = stream_context_create(['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth"]]);
$homepage = file_get_contents("http://example.com/requested.file", false, $context );
```

I still keep getting a failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized.

I checked multiple times that the userdata I try to log in with is correct.

Comment: what are you trying to do, login?

Comment: yes. I am trying to login to a site with a http login.

Comment: do you have a login page for that site or just a get value like http://url/?login.. or http://url address?

Comment: I just get a popup when loading that site letting me to log in. As far as I know it is the http authentification

Comment: pop up , that is javascript or ajax  in php you can create a popup but with a url address . but with javascript and ajax, pop up can just happen just like that. do you have admin access for that site?

Comment: no I don't
To explain some more:
That "popup" has two input fields for username and password and it's style is kinda similar to the alert() function of javascript